# Usual topology is finer than cofinite topology on set of real numbers

Tags: general-topology

How to show that usual topology is finer than cofinite topology on the set of real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are closed in the usual topology, hence cofinite sets are open in it.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy: show that every cofinite set is open in the standard topology.